# In which JAR is the com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata.session.SessionProcessor located?

Tags: 2011, smarttarget

My webapp complains about not being able to find: **`com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata.session.SessionProcessor`**.

Where is this located? I cannot find any `com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata`. I looked in jars such as:

- `cd_ambient.jar`
- `smarttarget_core.jar`
- `smarttarge_cartridge.jar`

It's on SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 (probably HR1)

Full error:

> Caused by: com.tridion.ambientdata.AmbientDataException: Cannot find
>   claim processor implementation class:
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata.session.SessionProcessor  at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.EngineFactory.claimProcessorDefinitionFromConfig(EngineFactory.java:114)
>     at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.EngineFactory.cartridgeDefinitionFromConfig(EngineFactory.java:68)
>     at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.EngineFactory.newEngine(EngineFactory.java:46)
>     at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter.init(AmbientDataServletFilter.java:99)
>     ... 45 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata.session.SessionProcessor  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)   at
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.EngineFactory.claimProcessorDefinitionFromConfig(EngineFactory.java:110)
>     ... 48 more

Comment: I got this error when I enabled session_cartrigde_conf.xml in the cd_ambient_conf.xml. I did not expect to that to use any SmartTarget stuff. I did not investigate this, so there might be something else which causes this error to occur at the moment when I enable session_cartridge_conf.xml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the **session_cartridge.jar** which is part of SmartTarget

It is located in the **Ambient Data Framework\cartridges** folder on the cd layout